# Center align tds inside a table without creating empty tds?

Tags: html, css

I have  a table and i want 2 tds centered like
**      Hello | World ** without adding empty tds before and after ?
I have something like this which works fine but i dont want to add extra tds and do it the same way

```
<table class="alignCenter" style="border:1px solid black">  
                <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;
                </td>
                    <td class="searchField">
                        <select id ="exactField">
                             <option value="default">Request num</option>
                        </select>   
                        <input type="text" class="textBox" id="exactValue"/>
                    </td>   
                    <td class="tableButtons">
                        <button type="button" class="clear" ><bdi>${Clear_Button}</bdi></button>
                        <button type="button" class="submit" ><bdi>${Search_Button}</bdi></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

**CSS**

```
table,.alignCenter {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: left;
table-layout: fixed;
font-size: 0.9em;
}


table tr td,.alignCenter tr td {
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid black;
vertical-align: top;
padding: 5px 2px 5px 2px;
}

.alignCenter tr td {
text-align : center;
}
.tableButtons {
 width:250px;   
}

.searchField {
 width:300px;
 }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4G9Kz/)

Comment: Doesn't look like a tabular data

Comment: @Mr.Alien check the working fiddle

Comment: @user2125700 Do not use tables for layout.

Comment: @DJDavid98 The form is huge in terms of content and has very complex structure so i moved to tables otherwise i was using divs

Comment: @user2125700 Correct, otherwise you'd use divs. Which would be the correct way to lay out something that isn't tabular data.

Answer (score 3):

Why you even need 4 td's to accomplish something like that?

Just use a single `td` (I would use a simple div for this)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4G9Kz/1/)

```
<table class="alignCenter" style="border:1px solid black">  
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id ="exactField">
                 <option value="default">Request num</option>
            </select>   
            <input type="text" class="textBox" id="exactValue"/>            
            <button type="button" class="clear" ><bdi>${Clear_Button}</bdi></button>
            <button type="button" class="submit" ><bdi>${Search_Button}</bdi></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Alien i specifically have to use 2 tds as per requirement or i already that before +1 anyways

Comment: @user2125700 Any specific reason for using tables for this? and that too specifically with 4 tds?

Comment: Requirements i know its painful but i was just wondering if i could do it without using any blank tds

Comment: You don't need to use `&nbsp;`, also if you've a 4 column table, you can simply colspan 4 td's in 2 and later use `text-align: right;` for 1st and `left` for the 2nd respectively

Comment: i added nbsp just so it doesnot collapse instead of putting it empty and i will give it a try thanks

Comment: @user2125700 Learn how to use `colspan` if you've a 4 column table and you need this piece of html at the end of the table, than you can use colspan, also you can use straight `colspan="4"`

Comment: I know how to use `colspan` but for this case i think it doesnt make any sense using it

Comment: @user2125700 It doesn't make sense in using tables, It must be a special reason for you to use tables

Comment: I used divs but the structure is such i was forced back to use tables and here i am with using something so specific  for a particular table

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work?

html..

```
<table style="border:1px solid black">  
                    <tr>
                        <td class="alignright" >
                            <select id ="exactField">
                                 <option value="default">Request num</option>
                            </select>   
                            <input type="text" class="textBox" id="exactValue"/></td>
                        <td class="alignleft" >
                            <button type="button" class="clear" ><bdi>${Clear_Button}</bdi></button>
                            <button type="button" class="submit" ><bdi>${Search_Button}</bdi></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

css..

```
table,.alignright {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: right;
  table-layout: fixed;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
table,.alignleft {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: left;
  table-layout: fixed;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}


.tableButtons {
  width:250px;  
}

.searchField {
  width:300px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4G9Kz/2/)

Comment: nice try but thats a big no no

Comment: for what reason, so i can try and change it?